# 301 redirect for drupal to clean url

Tags: drupal, url-rewriting

I need to write 301 redirects to a clean url in drupal. For example:

```
redirect 301 /old/mypage /new/mypage
```

The problem is, it redirects to www.example.com/new/mypage?q=mypage
I need it to go to www.example.com/new/mypage

I have clean urls enabled on my site. Any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check [301 Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/domain_301_redirect) for this requirement of yours.

Thanks

Comment: This module doesn't seem to address my needs.  I need the redirects to not append the ?q= but simply direct to the page indicated in my example.  The main domain remains the same.